# Python unit-testing: view annotated coverage report in terminal

Tags: python, linux, unit-testing, code-coverage, python-unittest

I'm using Python's unittest for testing, and I know I can view per-source-file annotated coverage report in browser by exporting it to HTML files with:

```
coverage run -m unittest *_test.py
coverage html
```

But I want to view this in Linux/Unix command line: view a given source file, with covered lines marked with green, and missed lines marked with red.

I tested several terminal web browsers (w3m, links, elinks, links2) and none of them can display these html files in a readable manner.

Maybe I'm missing something, because it looks like a very obvious feature to have in "coverage" or "green" or other testing tools, but I can't find anything!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to get colored source file reports in the terminal.  You can use `coverage annotate` to get annotated source files currently.

Perhaps it makes sense now to get rid of the old-style annotate, and replace it with a rich terminal report.